# Problem when validating city field when registering new address at checkout M2

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping-address

In Magento 2 I replaced the city text field with a select in the new address registration form in the checkout, but selecting a select option and trying to send the form shows that the field is required, it appears that it does not recognize the value.

The procedure I followed was as follows:

In my module, file checkout_index_index.xml

```
<item name="shipping-address-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
  <item name="city" xsi:type="array">
      <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/form/element/select</item>
      </item>
      <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">900</item>
  </item>
</item>
```

And my element template html is:

```
<select name="city" id="city" class="city"></select>
```

When hit save:

[image]

The values of the select are being populated with ajax when the zip code is filled.

when I click Save the following js error is displayed:

[image]

How to make it work?